# Django ViewSet filtering with Foreign Key name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 Django models with the following structure:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)

class Component(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)
    title = models.ForeignKey('Title', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

So i have a ComponentViewSet as follows:

```
class ComponentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Component.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ComponentSerializer

    filter_fields = {
        'id': ['exact'],
        'code': ['exact', 'istartswith'],
        'title': ['exact'],
    }
```

So if i want to filter Components via Title the URL is http://localhost:8010/api/components/?title=1.
How can I make a view filtering with Title.code value i.e http://localhost:8010/api/components/?title=Test ?

Comment: Is your `filter_fields` config working?

Comment: Yes they are working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
class ComponentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Component.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ComponentSerializer

    filter_fields = {
        'id': ['exact'],
        'code': ['exact', 'istartswith'],
        'title__code': ['exact'],
    }
```

but, the url will become,

```
 http://localhost:8010/api/components/?title__code=Test
```

---

**Suggestion**
You could use [**django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/), which has more control over ***URL filtering***